# JS deleting item in Todolist with localstorage. It deletes the index in order (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) How to specify my delete item when I click it?

Tags: javascript, arrays, storage, local

Newbie here... When using my deleteItem function in javascript

Lets say I added a list items 1, 2, 3, 4 and in my localStorage it will equal as an array of [1, 2, 3, 4]

so when I click the delete button on lets say number 3 to be remove.

What happens is 3 will be deleted in the "Page" but not in my localStorage

localStorage shows [2, 3, 4] (1 is removed instead of 3)

it should be [1, 2, 4]

and when hit page refresh.. The list items in the page will change to 2, 3, 4 equal to localStorage

It means it always remove the first array in order up to the last array

```js
    const add = document.getElementById("additem")
    const remove = document.getElementById("removeitem")
    const input = document.getElementById("inputBlank")
    const contain = document.getElementById("container")

    const LOCAL_STORAGE_PREFIX = "TODO_APP_V1"
    const TODOS_STORAGE_KEY = `${LOCAL_STORAGE_PREFIX}- todos`
    let todos = loadTodos() // Load from local storage


    /// Appending all
    add.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        let btn = document.createElement('button');
        let paragraph = document.createElement("th");
        btn.innerText="x";
        btn.style.background="";
        paragraph.innerText = input.value;
        if (input.value === "") return alert("Write text in the blank field")
        todos.push(paragraph.innerText)
        input.value = "";
        paragraph.appendChild(btn);
        contain.appendChild(paragraph)
        saveTodos()

        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            deleteItem(todos) // calling delete function for localstorage
            contain.removeChild(paragraph)
        })  
        remove.addEventListener('click', function () {
            localStorage.removeItem(TODOS_STORAGE_KEY)
        })
    })

    ///Saving to local storage
    function saveTodos() {
        localStorage.setItem(TODOS_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos))
    }

    //Getting from local storage
    function loadTodos() {
        const todos = localStorage.getItem(TODOS_STORAGE_KEY)
        return JSON.parse(todos) || []
    }

///for localstorage
    todos.forEach((element) => {
        let paragraph = document.createElement("th");
        paragraph.innerText = element;
        let btn = document.createElement("button");
        btn.innerText = "x";
        btn.style.background="";
        paragraph.appendChild(btn);
        contain.appendChild(paragraph);

        btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            deleteItem(todos) // calling delete function for localstorage
            contain.removeChild(paragraph)
        })
        
        remove.addEventListener('click', function () {
            localStorage.removeItem(TODOS_STORAGE_KEY)

        })

    });

///delete function
    function deleteItem(index) {
        let todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(TODOS_STORAGE_KEY))
        todos.splice(index, 1) 
        localStorage.setItem(TODOS_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(todos)) 
    }
```

Comment: You're passing your entire array of todos to the delete function rather than the index you want to delete.

Comment: I see sir but I can't seem to pass it specifically to the index that I want to delete. I can't figure it out

Comment: Try `todos.forEach((element, index) =>{ }`  and then pass it to the function `deleteItem(index)`.

Comment: forEach provides second parameter that gives index of each element

Comment: Thank you sir/mam it works fine now. Thanks!!